# print one xml output from multiple perl scripts that prints different xml outputs

Tags: xml, perl

I have asked this question before but did not get the satisfied answer as i did not include the proper example to look at.

I have multiple scripts that uses xsl to print xml output from those scripts. i want to write a one master script that calls those scripts and combine the out and print one output. could someone please help me with this?

```
#Example Script 1

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $output = '';
my $debug = 0;
my $path;
GetOptions('path=s' => \$path,'output=s' => \$output, 'debug=i' => \$d
+ebug);

if($output eq ''){
    die ("parameter --output=s is missing");
}     
open my $xmloutput, ">", $outputFile or die "can not open $outputFile 
+";
 print $xmloutput "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-s
+tylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"book.xsl\"?>\n<Books>\n";

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("$path");
print $xmloutput " <bookDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput "  <bookName>$data</bookName> \n";
print $xmloutput " </bookDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput " </Books> \n";
close $xmloutput;
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
EXAMPLE 2
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $output = '';
my $debug = 0;
my $path;
GetOptions('path=s' => \$path,'output=s' => \$output, 'debug=i' => \$d
+ebug);

if($output eq ''){
    die ("parameter --output=s is missing");
}     
open my $xmloutput, ">", $outputFile or die "can not open $outputFile 
+";
 print $xmloutput "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-s
+tylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"Piano.xsl\"?>\n<Piano>\n";

my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $parser->XMLin("$path");
print $xmloutput " <PianoDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput "  <PianoName>$data</PianoName> \n";
print $xmloutput " </PianoDetails> \n";
print $xmloutput " </Piano> \n";
close $xmloutput;
```

THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING.

```
  my $output = '';


   my $example1 = `perl script1.pl --path=c:/cygwin/home/username/directory --debug=1`;
    my $example2 = `perl script2.pl --path=c:/cygwin/home/username/directory --debug=1`;

 open my $finaloutput, ">" $output or die "cant open the file";
  print $finaloutput "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-stylesheet     
          type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"final.xsl\"?>\n<OutputDestination>\n";

   my @attachscript  = ($example1, $example2);

   for my $attached (@attachscript) {
     print $finaloutput "<outputgoes_here_from_script> $attached   
                         </outputgoes_here_from_script>
    }

     PRINT $finaloutput "</OutputDestination>"
     close $finaloutput;
```

Is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: Could you give an example of how those scripts are called?

Comment: Hello @jimtut i have added the to top what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If script1 and script2 can't be converted to Perl Modules and called directly (as functions) within your wrapper (or even just rewritten into a single new script), I'd consider just doing this in the wrapper:

```
open (STDOUT, ">$output") or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";
print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"final.xsl\"?>\n<OutputDestination>\n";
print "<outputgoes_here_from_script>";
`perl script1.pl --path=c:/cygwin/home/username/directory --debug=1`;
print "</outputgoes_here_from_script>";
print "<outputgoes_here_from_script>";
`perl script2.pl --path=c:/cygwin/home/username/directory --debug=1`;
print "</outputgoes_here_from_script>";
print "</OutputDestination>";
close(STDOUT);
```

You might need a "print" before the back-ticked system calls, but try it that way first.  But, it's not much different than your approach, just skipping the need to save the output from each script.